# How to mock AWS TimestreamWrite by jest

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jestjs, amazon-timestream

This project is to record data by AWS Timestream, and it works well.

However, I'm failed to mock AWS TimestreamWrite by using jest. I tried some ways but not working. Can someone help me?

My files as below:

#### ledger-service.js

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const enums = require("./enums");

var https = require("https");
var agent = new https.Agent({
  maxSockets: 5000,
});
const tsClient = new AWS.TimestreamWrite({
  maxRetries: 10,
  httpOptions: {
    timeout: 20000,
    agent: agent,
  },
});

module.exports = {
  log: async function (audit) {
    try {
      if (Object.keys(audit).length !== 0) {
        if (!isPresent(audit, "name")) {
          throw new Error("Name shouldn't be empty");
        }

        if (!isPresent(audit, "value")) {
          throw new Error("Value shouldn't be empty");
        }

        return await writeRecords(recordParams(audit));
      } else {
        throw new Error("Audit object is empty");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
  },
};
function isPresent(obj, key) {
  return obj[key] != undefined && obj[key] != null && obj[key] != "";
}
function recordParams(audit) {
  const currentTime = Date.now().toString(); // Unix time in milliseconds
  const dimensions = [
    // { Name: "client", Value: audit["clientId"] },
    { Name: "user", Value: audit["userId"] },
    { Name: "entity", Value: audit["entity"] },
    { Name: "action", Value: audit["action"] },
    { Name: "info", Value: audit["info"] },
  ];

  return {
    Dimensions: dimensions,
    MeasureName: audit["name"],
    MeasureValue: audit["value"],
    MeasureValueType: "VARCHAR",
    Time: currentTime.toString(),
  };
}
function writeRecords(records) {
  try {
    const params = {
      DatabaseName: enums.AUDIT_DB,
      TableName: enums.AUDIT_TABLE,
      Records: [records],
    };

    return tsClient.writeRecords(params).promise();
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
}
```

#### ledger-service.spec.js

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const audit = require("./ledger-service");

describe("ledger-service", () => {

    beforeEach(async () => {
        jest.resetModules();
    });
  
    afterEach(async () => {
      jest.resetAllMocks();
    });

    it("It should write records when all success", async () => {
        const mockAudit={
            name: 'testName',
            value: 'testValue',
            userId: 'testUserId',
            entity: 'testEntity',
            action: 'testAction',
            info: 'testInfo',
        };

        const mockWriteRecords = jest.fn(() =>{
            console.log('mock success')
            return { promise: ()=> Promise.resolve()}
         });

        const mockTsClient={
            writeRecords: mockWriteRecords
        }

        jest.spyOn(AWS,'TimestreamWrite');
        AWS.TimestreamWrite.mockImplementation(()=>mockTsClient);

        //a=new AWS.TimestreamWrite();
        //a.writeRecords();   //these two lines will pass the test and print "mock success"

        await audit.log(mockAudit); //this line will show "ConfigError: Missing region in config"

        expect(mockWriteRecords).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I just think the the AWS I mocked doesn't pass into the `ledger-service.js`. Is there a way to fix that?

Thanks

### updates: Taking hoangdv's suggestion

I am thinking `jest.resetModules(); jest.resetAllMocks();` don't work. If I put the "It should write records when all success" as the first test, it will pass the test. However, it will fail if there is one before it.

#### Pass

```
  it("It should write records when all success", async () => {
    const mockAudit = {
      name: 'testName',
      value: 'testValue',
      userId: 'testUserId',
      entity: 'testEntity',
      action: 'testAction',
      info: 'testInfo',
    };

    await audit.log(mockAudit);

    expect(AWS.TimestreamWrite).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      maxRetries: 10,
      httpOptions: {
        timeout: 20000,
        agent: expect.any(Object),
      },
    });
    expect(mockWriteRecords).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it("It should throw error when audit is empty", async () => {
    const mockAudit = {};

    await expect(audit.log(mockAudit)).rejects.toThrow(`Audit object is empty`);
  });
```

#### Failed

```
  it("It should throw error when audit is empty", async () => {
    const mockAudit = {};

    await expect(audit.log(mockAudit)).rejects.toThrow(`Audit object is empty`);
  });

  it("It should write records when all success", async () => {
    const mockAudit = {
      name: 'testName',
      value: 'testValue',
      userId: 'testUserId',
      entity: 'testEntity',
      action: 'testAction',
      info: 'testInfo',
    };

    await audit.log(mockAudit);

    expect(AWS.TimestreamWrite).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      maxRetries: 10,
      httpOptions: {
        timeout: 20000,
        agent: expect.any(Object),
      },
    });
    expect(mockWriteRecords).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ledger-service.js` you call `new AWS.TimestreamWrite` "before" `module.exports`, this means it will be called with actual logic instead of mock.

The solution is just mock `AWS` before you call `require("./ledger-service");`

**ledger-service.spec.js**

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

describe("ledger-service", () => {
  let audit;
  let mockWriteRecords;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockWriteRecords = jest.fn(() => {
      return { promise: () => Promise.resolve() }
    });

    jest.spyOn(AWS, 'TimestreamWrite');
    AWS.TimestreamWrite.mockImplementation(() => ({
      writeRecords: mockWriteRecords
    }));

    audit = require("./ledger-service"); // this line
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules(); // reset module to update change for each require call
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it("It should write records when all success", async () => {
    const mockAudit = {
      name: 'testName',
      value: 'testValue',
      userId: 'testUserId',
      entity: 'testEntity',
      action: 'testAction',
      info: 'testInfo',
    };

    await audit.log(mockAudit);

    expect(AWS.TimestreamWrite).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      maxRetries: 10,
      httpOptions: {
        timeout: 20000,
        agent: expect.any(Object),
      },
    });
    expect(mockWriteRecords).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me, but I think `resetModules()`, `resetAllMocks` don't work, see me updates on that